# Stop displaying "Unsupported .vdproj" warning

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, vdproj

I am working on an older project that contains `.vdproj` installer projects and am using Visual Studio 2013.

The problem is that for every `.vdproj` project I receive a warning – thus, after opening the solution, I have to close about 50 warnings.

Is there a way how to stop displaying those warnings?

**Edit:**

The same issue arises with Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install a [Microsoft extension that enables `.vdproj` installer projects in VS 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d).

Comment: VS 2013 Update 4 did not resolve the issue for me, but the installer-projects extension that krill-a mentions did.

Comment: Also, per my edit to the question, the same problem arises with VS 2015, and MS has released an [updated extension to similarly address the issue](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/003f3135-bbca-4eb2-951d-88820065a124).

Answer (score 7):

@krill-a's answer regarding VS 2013 is spot-on.

Since the same problem occurs in VS 2015, note that Microsoft has released an updated extension to solve the problem in it.

Like the VS 2013 installer-projects extension, you can [download the updated installer-projects extension from the Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/003f3135-bbca-4eb2-951d-88820065a124) to add support for `.vdproj` projects in VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

**For Visual Studio 2019 (possibly 2017) you need to add the installer extension**.

In Visual Studio:

1. Select the menu item "Extensions"
2. Select "Manage Extensions"
3. In the left-hand pane, select "Online"
4. In the search box, search for "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects"
5. Install
6. Load your project